# Java: When adding an object to a tree set exception gets thrown

Tags: java, exception, treeset

When try to add an object to my TreeSet, this exception pops up.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Circle.compareTo(Shape.java:47)
    at Circle.compareTo(Shape.java:23)
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at CircleTreeSet.main(CircleTreeSet.java:24)
```

All I'm doing in my main method is creating the TreeSet, creating a Object, and adding it to the set.

Here is the main method:

```
class CircleTreeSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Circle> cs = new TreeSet<Circle>();

        Circle circle1 = new Circle("circle1", 1);

        cs.add(circle1);
    }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
class Circle extends Shape implements Comparable<Circle> {
    private static String name;
    private int radius;

    Circle(String n, int r) {
        super(n);
        radius = r;
    }

    public double area() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double perim() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    public int compareTo(Circle c) {
        return name.compareTo(c.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to show your code in addition to the stack trace of your exception.

Comment: Could you please check that:- All elements inserted into the set have implement the Comparable interface?

Comment: I'm interested in seeing how your `Circle` has implemented `compareTo`; that is, does it behave correctly when compared to `null`?

Comment: looks like you have inserted a `null` value into your `TreeMap` and the `compareTo` implementation in `Circle` does not check for `null` values...

Comment: Share the Shape class as well.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: see this: [compareTo() implementation problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174791/compareto-implementation-problems)

Comment: Remove `private static String name;` from Circle as it's hiding the one defined in Shape.

Comment: @PoByBolek what your saying is i should have a check in my compareTo method handles when the Tree set checks to make sure there are no duplicates and it just checks against empty slots in the set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts.

1. I'm not sure what purpose the `name` variable would actually *serve*, since there's no way to access it from outside of the class, nor is it used *inside* the class.  If it's not used, remove it.
2. Your `compareTo` is simply incorrect.  Think of a comparison like this.

   - How do I determine equivalence?  How are two `Circles` deemed equivalent?
   - How do I determine the natural ordering?  In what way are `Circles` ordered by?

A `TreeSet` cares about the [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) of its elements.

---

Let's define some laws about `Circles`, then.

- A `Circle` is equivalent to another `Circle` if and only if their radius is equivalent.
- A `Circle` is lesser in rank to another `Circle` if and only if their radius is lesser rank to another `Circle`.
- A `Circle` is higher in rank to any nonexistent `Circle`.

Let's move forward with those laws, and define `compareTo`.  To fully complete this, though, we need a getter for `radius`:

```
public Integer getRadius() {
    return Integer.valueOf(radius);
}
```

I'm leveraging `Integer` instead of `int`, since `Integer` is also `Comparable`.  It makes our `compareTo` a little easier.

```
public int compareTo(final Circle other) {
    if(other == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return Integer.valueOf(radius).compareTo(other.getRadius());
    }
}
```

An alternative way, as pointed out in the comments, would also allow you to take the difference of our radius, and the other object's radius, which would satisfy the general contract for `Comparable` - if the difference is 0, they're equivalent; if it's greater than 0, then it's larger; is it's less than 0, then it's smaller.

To do that, we change our getter to return `int`:

```
public int getRadius() {
    return radius;
}
```

...and modify our `compareTo` as such:

```
public int compareTo(final Circle other) {
    if(other == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return radius - other.getRadius();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just more of an exercise in my programming, I'm a bit rusty and have some upcoming exams

Comment: Any specific reason you use `Integer` instead of `int` for `getRadius()`?

Comment: @PoByBolek:  "I'm leveraging Integer instead of int, since Integer is also Comparable. It makes our compareTo a little easier."

Comment: @Makoto And what's wrong with `return radius - other.getRadius()` if `getRadius()` returns `int`?

Comment: @PoByBolek  **Absolutely nothing.**  If one wants to avoid autoboxing, then that could be seen as a viable solution.

Comment: @Makoto but you're probably right. `Integer.compareTo(Integer)` is easier to grasp then subtracting to `int`s for comparison... (at least for me)...  
But now that you edited your post, also fine :)

Answer (score 2):

`name` is static and is null because it is never set. I think you have misunderstood the meaning of `static`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out I didn't mean for that to be static at all

Comment: Yes, `name` is null, and that's what causes the `compareTo` to blow up.  But, does that really fix the issue?

Comment: removing static yielded no benefits but its still an incorrect use of it...thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `name` of your `Circle` should probably not be `static` and you should assign a value to it in the `Circle` constructor:

```
class Circle extends Shape implements Comparable<Circle> {
    private String name;
    private int radius;

    Circle(String n, int r) {
        this.name = n; // this is crucial
        this.radius = r;
    }

    public int compareTo(Circle other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a NullPointerException, as you **never** initialize the static variable *name*.
As a result, when you invoke the method *compareTo(...)*, the time the code

```
return name.compareTo(c.name);
```

is executed, name has a null value. You are trying to invoke a method (*comparedTo(...)*) via this null-valued variable, so this will result in a NullPointerException throwing.

Addidionally, having the *name* set as static will probably result in its value overwriting everytime you create an object. Static variables are considered as "unique" and "common" in a sense among all created objects, as their lifetime extends across the entire run of the program. To take it one step further, static variables are stored in a different place of computer memory than local variables or objects are stored.